# Display different images in next view when button pressed swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

How to show different images in same next viewcontroller when button is pressed.

When first button is pressed it should show one image and when second button is pressed it should show other image in second view controller.

It can be done by use three different view controller and using segue just avoid adding many view controller I want it do display in same view controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it not be better to use a UIPagingController?

Comment: I think no because when first button is pressed it shows one image and we go back to first view and when second button is pressed it should go to same second view but should show different image.

Comment: Why do you need a new ViewController for that? Just change the image of the UIImageView in the same ViewController.

Comment: Exactly but how 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the original view controller, on `prepare`, set the name of the image that should be displayed on the next view controller.

On the next view controller you just read that and name and create a UIImage from it.

Origin VC:

```
var imageToLoad : String = ""

@IBAction func btnA(_ sender: UIButton) {
   imageToLoad = "imageA"
}

@IBAction func btnB(_ sender: UIButton) {
   imageToLoad = "imageB"
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if let destinarionVC = segue.destination as! NEXT_VIEW_CONTROLLER {
    destinarionVC.imageName = self.imageToLoad
  }
}
```

Next VC:

```
var imageName : String = ""
var image : UIImage

override func viewDidLoad() { //Or wherever you need it to be
  image = UIImage(name: imageName)
}
```

Comment: Done it... Just be sure to use the image wherever you need on the next VC, not necessarily on viewDidLoad

Comment: in the second line after prepare it gives erroe : initilaizer for conditional binding must be optional. In Second View I have UIImageview instead of uiimage. I used perform segeue with indentifier to go to next view when button is clicked.

Comment: Change ! For ? For The error you got. If you have a UIImageView just initialization that with the image I wrote the code for...

Comment: It Worked. Its hard to be newbie. Thanks

Comment: when you press the image it goes to third view and when I come back from third view to second view now image does not display. Do I have to do same things as in first view to load the image or is there any simple solutions?

Comment: It depends is how your code is written... If your loading the image on viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, then in every change of VC you'll have to set the image you want on prepare. You should analyze your code and investigate why it isn't displaying the image

Comment: Yes I am loading the image in viewDidLoad. I can also display the image now  but the problem is when I come to second view from third view it should display the image which was displayed when button from view was pressed. In first view there was 2 buttons so it was easy now its only one button which should display images based on first view action. So now it is displaying same image I declared in third view.

Comment: Look. I honestly think you should study a little the basics of swift... It seems to me you have no idea what you're doing and are just trying to guess everything. It doesn't seem to be a hard problem to figure out, but I would need your code. But the biggest problem here is, because you haven't studied the basics, you never know why a situation is happening and how to make it right.... Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to be rude, but it would be better if you studied...

Answer (score 0):

Try using Carbonkit Framwork

https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit

You can use a single view controller and change animation and it feels like its moving to another viewcontroller. Actually its moving to another view controller but it is same view controller as before.